# .Net 5 - Authentication Cookie not saved when deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, cookies

this is my scenario:
I have a .Net5 WEB API application and a React one that invoke its APIs. The authentication flow is made using cookies.

These lines are set in my *Startup.cs* file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(_ => { _.Cookie.Name = "_auth"; });
    ...
}
```

The controller method used by the login API is

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Login user")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login([FromBody] UserLogin request, [FromQuery] string returnUrl)
{
    returnUrl = await this.accountData.LoginAsync(request, returnUrl, HttpContext);
    return Ok(new SuccessResult<string>(returnUrl, true));
}
```

And, the method that performs the login action is

```
private Task PerformSignIn(List<Claim> claims, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, HttpContext httpContext)
{
    string authenticationScheme = this.GetAuthenticationScheme();
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationScheme, USER_CLAIM, null);

    return httpContext.SignInAsync(authenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authenticationProperties);
}
```

So, when I use the local version of my backend application, either hosted on IIS Express and Docker, the login action works like a charm, the frontend application invokes the API that returns 200 and, along this, the **_auth** cookies is saved on browser.

**Problem**

Then, I hosted the backend application on a test server on IIS using publish through folder.
It is an application under a website and uses a dedicated application pool.
I changed the endpoint used by the frontend application to make it works using the IIS' hosted application, it uses *http* protocol. The login is invoked and it returns 200 with the correct payload, but the **_auth** cookie is not set and the subsequent calls fails with a 401 response.

I cannot understand why the cookie is not saved on browser when deployed on IIS.

**Update**

I tried creating a new website in IIS that uses, as target, the folder where the .Net5 application is deployed and not using it as *sub application* and the cookie is correctly saved, in this way.

Comment: Are you running on HTTPS?

Comment: No, as I wrote I use http

Comment: If the cookie is marked as Secure (as it should for an identity cookie) it won't be send over HTTP.

Comment: Try to change to https and add cookie_secure header and test again.